# How to create a 3x3 grid with sub child grids 2x2 and 1x1?

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently i am using nested linearlayouts and nested weightsum and layout weight to achieve what i wanted in the screenshots below.

I did notice however that as the lint-warning suggests, that my one of my out-dated phone is slightly slow. As nested weight sums seems to hinder the performance of a device.

This is my linearlayout code currently. And I would like to achieve the screenshot attached. Are there any other way that i could achieve it without using extensively nested weightsums? I have seen constraintLayout that does similar things, but how do i actually use it?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_layout"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@id/next">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#345678"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#3bcad5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#3ca3d2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#123456"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#310911"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#92F358"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can set above layout using ConstraintLayout like below :

**my_file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">




        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6666667" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_green"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_orange"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_red"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_orange"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_purple"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view_red"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_green" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_blue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_green" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

main Constraint-Layout is set square and second Constraint-Layout create all other view. this is **exactly become like your screen shot**.